# Cloning the base working environment in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

My base working environment works perfectly with several key existing packages, however, one package has has had some very useful updates that I want to test out. How can I create a clone of my base working environment so that I can avoid touching the base working environment? For whatever reason, the clone button in Anaconda is greyed out when I try to clone the base working environment:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be because an exact clone of `base` is not possible as `conda` is always only installed in `base`. You can however simply go into a terminal and do

```
conda create -n baseClone --clone base
```

which will create a cloned env called `baseClone` with all packages from base except those that cannot be cloned (e.g. `conda`)